# How to do SEO for eCommerce website?

Tags: seo, google, ecommerce, social-media, ppc

What are the steps required to generate traffic for eCommerce sites like online shopping  sites?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, visit the help center.

Comment: I want do seo for eCommerce site,that site done by preshtashop

Comment: There are entire books written on this subject.   Please limit your questions to a single aspect of SEO that can be answered in a couple paragraphs.   If you are new to SEO try searching Google for an appropriate SEO tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your main starting point should be the same as any other SEO.

- Good quality, unique product descriptions and meta descriptions.
- Good URL and code structure
- Product reviews to generate unique and fresh content
- Sitemaps that are included in Google Webmaster Tools
- Marking pages up with schema.org microdata to increase click throughs

I really could keep going, but that gives you a solid starting point.